# Trying to install a gem on ruby (Windows 10)

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Whenever I try to install a gem on the latest version ruby with the devkit I get an error saying that I have to install development tools first! Please help because I really want to install beEF on my PC. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should check this out if you haven't: https://rubyinstaller.org/

then on that site it has instructions on how install the development kit.

if you look at the documentation for devkit https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit follow the instructions

1. cd to devkit directory
2. `ruby dk.rb init`
3. `ruby dk.rb install`

After those steps above try to install your gem again.

Comment: It did fix half of it but after it just says this error : current directory: C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-2.1.0/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR="
generating generator-x64-mingw32.def
compiling generator.c
make: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc: Command not found
make: *** [generator.o] Error 127

Comment: I think I found the problem, I have a bit Dev Kit. I will keep this open just incise I encounter any further problems.

Comment: Thank you for your help!